# R ggplot barplot; Fill based on two separate variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

A picture says more than a thousand words. As you can see, my `fill` is based on the variable `variable`.

Within each bar there is however multiple data entities (black borders) since the discrete variable `complexity` make them unique. What I am trying to find is something that makes each section of the bar more distinguishable than the current look. Preferable would be if it was something like shading.

[image: http://s12.postimage.org/ltgs677ul/snapshot2.png]

Here's an example (not the same dataset, since the original was imported):

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Complexity Method Sens Spec MMC
1 L Alpha 50 20 10
2 M Alpha 40 30 80
3 H Alpha 10 10 5
4 L Beta 70 50 60
5 M Beta 49 10 80
6 H Beta 90 17 48
7 L Gamma 19 5 93
8 M Gamma 18 39 4
9 H Gamma 10 84 74", sep = "", header=T)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
short.m <- melt(dat)
ggplot(short.m, aes(x=Method, y= value/100 , fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", colour="black") + 
    coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is far from perfect, but hopefully a step in the right direction, as it's dodged by `variable`, but still manages to represent `Complexity` in some way:

```
ggplot(short.m, aes(x=Method, y=value/100, group=variable, fill=variable, alpha=Complexity,)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", colour="black") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.1, 0.5, 1)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant! Precisely what I needed to continue.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that bars obscure eachother. 

In Alpha Spec there's actually a H bar, but it's completely hidden since it was drawn first (H comes before L and M).

Since alpha values also add to eachother one can't tell which one is which (see Beta Spec). Obviously we know the middle line is for H, but the reader most likely won't.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `alpha=complexity` might work:

```
ggplot(short.m, aes(x=Method, y= value/100 , fill=variable, alpha=complexity)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", colour="black") + coord_flip()
```

Comment: Ill try to add in a reproducible example this monday.

Comment: The problem with using alpha (much like using colour) is that the bars will be dodged from eachother. What I'm ideally is trying to get is stacked alpha (Complexity) and dodged variable (which is melted MMC, Sens and Spec)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to separate your `Method` and `variable` factors. Here are two ways to do that:

Use `facet_wrap()`:

```
    ggplot(short.m, aes(x=variable, y=value/100, fill=Complexity)) + 
    facet_wrap(~ Method) + geom_bar(position="stack", colour="black") +
    scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.1, 0.5, 1)) + coord_flip()
```

Use both on the x-axis:

```
    ggplot(short.m, aes(x=Method:variable, y=value/100, group=Method, fill=variable, alpha=Complexity,)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack", colour="black") +
    scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.1, 0.5, 1)) + coord_flip()
```

Comment: I'll try it first thing tomorrow morning and see how it works out. ;)

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it doesn't really stack the bars, it just adds them on top of each other. As such two equally long Spec MC may appear different lengths since they aren't positioned parallel.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand what you were trying to do. In ggplot, "stack" means add them on top of each other. To my knowledge, the kind of stack you want is not possible in ggplot. I think this is your best option: `ggplot(short.m, aes(x=variable, y=value/100, fill=Complexity)) + facet_wrap(~ Method) + geom_bar(position="dodge", colour="black") + coord_flip()` or maybe `ggplot(short.m, aes(x=Method:variable, y=value/100, fill=Complexity)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", colour="black") + coord_flip()`